# Classpath issues - getJNIEnv failed

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, java-native-interface, g++

I have successfully compiled the JNI based Apache [libhdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html) (C++) on my Hadoop Sandbox / CentOS - no compilation errors or warnings:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.151.x86_64/include/ 
-I/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/usr/include/ -I/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop/bin 
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64/include/ 
-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/ 
-L/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop/lib/ -L/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop/lib/native 
-L/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop/lib/ -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/ 
-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/ 
-lhdfs -pthread -ljvm
```

Once I try to run the code, I get the following errors:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# ./test
Environment variable CLASSPATH not set!
getJNIEnv: getGlobalJNIEnv failed
Environment variable CLASSPATH not set!
getJNIEnv: getGlobalJNIEnv failed
```

If I run `hadoop classpath` in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# hadoop classpath 
/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop/conf:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-
235/hadoop/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop/.//:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-
hdfs/./:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-hdfs/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-
hdfs/.//:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-yarn/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-
yarn/.//:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-
235/hadoop-mapreduce/.//::jdbc-mysql.jar:mysql-connector-java-
5.1.17.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:mysql-connector-
java.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/tez/:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-
235/tez/lib/:/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/tez/conf
```

On the [Apache libhdfs page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html) it says:

> The most common problem is the CLASSPATH is not set properly when
>   calling a program that uses libhdfs. Make sure you set it to all the
>   Hadoop jars needed to run Hadoop itself as well as the right
>   configuration directory containing hdfs-site.xml. It is not valid to
>   use wildcard syntax for specifying multiple jars. It may be useful to
>   run hadoop classpath --glob or hadoop classpath --jar to generate the
>   correct classpath for your deployment. See Hadoop Commands Reference
>   for more information on this command.

I do however not get how to proceed after many trial and error attempts, I would therefore appreciate any help that could help me to solve this problem.

**Edit:** tried the following: CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath` ./test

...which gave me the following error: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried the following: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el6_9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server`

...and now the error is:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:`hadoop classpath` ./test
loadFileSystems error:
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
hdfsBuilderConnect(forceNewInstance=0, nn=default, port=0, kerbTicketCachePath=(NULL), userName=(NULL)) error:
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
hdfsOpenFile(/tmp/testfile.txt): constructNewObjectOfPath error:
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception: ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following could works for you:

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:`hadoop classpath` ./test
```

or only this:

```
CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath` ./test
```

Check out `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, maybe it could alter the java libraries used too.

And finally, a wrapper like the script below could be useful:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLASSPATH="AllTheJARs"
ARG0="$0"
EXEC_PATH="$( dirname "$ARG0" )"
"${EXEC_PATH}/test" $@
```

Comment: Just tried that. Please see the edit on my post. And btw, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Maybe into the CLASSPATH you have to append additional paths! Is the CLASSPATH empty? I mean, when you enter into the sandbox, execute ```echo $CLASSPATH```. Append the location of the JARs for the JDK you are using into the sandbox additionally to the paths and jars provided by the `hadoop classpath` command if the CLASSPATH is empty.

Comment: Executed `echo $CLASSPATH` and got a empty output. Could you please be more specific how to append the location of the JARs?

Comment: I solved it. I executed hadoop classpath --glob which outputted a lot of jars (many lines). I then created a CLASSPATH from all these jars: export CLASSPATH="AllTheJARs" and just run ./test and it did what it should. I don't know if this is a good solution - feedback is appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation is create a script as a wrapper to launch your "test" file or any other product you build at the end, so that you don't have to repeat the operation over and over again.

I have updated the original answer with the snippet for the wrapper.


Note: The snippet above have not been tested.

Comment: Perfect. I get it. Thanks.